# Path-dependent options valuation

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-neutral-measure, asian-option

Assume that we have an arbitrage-free and complete market. The well known formula for the arbitrage-free price of an attainable derivative $X$ at time $0 \leq t \leq T$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
V(t)=e^{-r(T-t)}E_Q(X \vert {\cal F}_t)
\end{align*}
Where $r$ is the risk-free interest rate and $E_Q$ is the expected value under the risk-neutral measure.

From my understanding, given a path-independent derivative with payoff $\Psi(S(T))$ for some function $\Psi$, we can calculate the arbitrage-free price by evaluating $E_Q(\Psi(S(T))\vert {\cal F}_t)$ right ? For instance, for the European call we have $\Psi(S(T))=\max(S(T)-K;0)$, where $S(T)$ is the stock price at time $T$ and $K$ is the strike price.

Now I wonder if this formula holds for path-dependent options too. For instance, if I want to calculate the arbitrage-free price of a fixed strike Asian call with payoff $\max(A(S)-K;0)$, where $A(S)$ is some sort of average, can I calculate
\begin{align*}
V(t)=e^{-r(T-t)}E_Q(\max(A(S)-K;0)\vert {\cal F}_t)
\end{align*}
?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Risk-neutral pricing

A time-$T$ payoff is an integrable, $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable random variable $\xi$. The value process of the discounted payoff is then a $\mathbb{Q}$-martingale, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
V_t=\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[\frac{B_t}{B_T}\xi\right],
\end{align*}
where $B_t$ is a locally risk-free bank account ($\text{d}B_t=r_tB_t\text{d}t$).

- *The above result essentially follows from the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the fact that $M_t=\mathbb{E}_t[X]$ is a martingale if $X$ is integrable (due to the tower law).*
- *If $r_t\equiv r$ is constant, we have $B_t=e^{rt}$ and $V_t=e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[\xi\right]$.*

### Does it work? Yes!

The only requirement is that $\xi$ is known (observable, measurable) at maturity $T$. There is no requirement that $\xi$ needs to be path-independent. Thus, $\xi$ can indeed be an average and standard risk-neutral pricing applies to (European-style) Asian options, i.e., $\xi=\max\{A-K,0\}$ is allowed! It makes no difference whether you consider arithmetic or geometric averages here, or whether you use averages as strike prices. Risk-neutral pricing also applies to other path-dependent exotic options such as (European-style) barrier options.

Indeed, semi-closed-form numerical methods for Asian options rely on explicitly on this risk-neutral pricing framework.

We also get some simple results: The identity $\max\{x-K,0\}-\max\{K-x,0\}=x-K$ gives a put-call parity for Asian options.

### Where's the problem?

The only problem is that computing the first moment of the option payoff is darn difficult. Most often, we're interested in arithmetic Asian options but we tend to model stock prices in an exponential form. That makes closed-form solutions very rare. Essentially, the distribution of the average $\int_t^T S_u\text{d}u$ is not really known for sensible stock price models. For geometric averages, the situation is a bit better.

### American options

The risk-neutral pricing formula does not apply to early exercise features (e.g., American put options). Their prices relate to the [Snell envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell_envelope), which is a supermartingale, see [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/58016/41821). Their prices can thus be decomposed into a European option (a martingale) and an early exercise correction term (Riesz decomposition or Doob-Meyer decomposition). The maths for these early exercise features is more difficult. Obviously, pricing American-style Asian options is a really difficult task (I'd opt for MC simulations)...

Comment: Very nice and concise answer! Since we average (integrate) expected (log) asset levels over time, do you second the idea that Asian options are only ‚mildly‘ exotic as we can use observed European option prices to calibrate a pricing model?

Comment: Kevin, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Kermittfrog Great comment! You’re saying that barrier/American/Asian options are all mildly exotic, because I can observe European vanilla prices for one maturity and use those market prices to infer the parameters of a model and then price the (mildly) exotic options in accordance with these parameters.. As I understand it, this is what one commonly does with exotic options. It’s our only possibility (as only vanilla prices are quoted) but I feel it’s not perfect (_see next comment_)

Comment: The payoffs of exotic options depend on the joint distribution of the stock prices at different time points. Observing European options for any given maturity $T$ gives us (at best) the marginal probability distribution of $S_T$ for that maturity. Because we compute the average of stock prices, we'd need a continuous flow of options expiring at any day (better: at every instant), from now until the Asian option expires. Given all these option prices, and assuming that the asset price is continuous (no jumps), then I guess we may be able infer the distribution of the average from market prices.

Comment: Yes; I was more thinking about whether (or not?) Asian options truly incorporate / require  the joint distribution, or whether sufficiently densely (in time) recovered point-in-time distributions (eg thru European options) would suffice.

Comment: @Kermittfrog I think you need the joint distribution of all future stock prices. Consider a Asian option that averages over two time points, $T_1$ and $T_2$  and expires at $T_2$. Suppose we observe all vanilla prices and can perfectly estimate that $\ln(S_{T_1})\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $\ln(S_{T_2})\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ . But is this enough to compute $\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{S_{T_1}+S_{T_2}}{2}-K\right)^+\right]$? I don't think so, you also need their correlation. But if you only observe vanillas, you cannot infer that joint distribution, can you? So you need a model assumption.

Comment: @Kevin yes, you are right. As we are not interested in the expectation of $\sum_t S_t$ (or its continuous time equivalent), but some $(\cdot)^+$ of it, we introduce the dependence on the joint distribution, hence we require more than ‘just’ European options for calibration. Thank you very much for the discussion and the example.

Comment: @Kermittfrog My pleasure, it was fun! I think there's a lot of research left to be done with exotic options! If only one had more time...

Comment: I am curious, who buys these options in general ? Imagine the time you need to invest to understand a trading strategy involving American Asians or stuff like that. Also I am sure that the market maker loves to hedge  these contracts ;)

Comment: @Lars Great question:) Many people buy Asian options over-the-counter. Imagine you want to hedge an ongoing exposure that does not only arise on one single day. Imagine you want to hedge several vanilla options with different maturities. Imagine you want to hedge against rising asset prices but a vanilla call option is too expensive. Imagine you want a contract that is less prone to market manipulation on the expiry day.... You see, Asian options are genuinely useful. And they may look complicated at a first glance, but if you spend enough time on quant finance, the task isn't too difficult :)

Comment: Never thought about it that way. I guess that this is the point where people like you come into play :D

Comment: Haha, thank you @Lars, I am flattered:D There are way smarter people than me on this forum and many real quants, not just some small wannabes like me:) But I am glad you found the answer useful.

Comment: Probably it is a bad question, but how can these exotic options be hedged? For example in the case of an asian option, what is the replicating portfolio?  It is known from the standard Black-Scholes model that when we replicate a vanilla European we have to hold $\Delta_t$ (the partial derivative of the option PV corresponding to the variable of the stock price) underlying in every  $t$, but how is the replication of an asian option (or any other exotic option) maintained?

Comment: @KapesMate It's a very good question but way too much for a comment here. You could ask your own question. There are several ways of how you can hedge exotics using vanilla options. I guess that is what people may do in practice: price it using a calibrated model and hedge all the Greeks using (tradable) vanillas

Comment: Okay, here is the link if anyone is interested: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/77751/hedging-exotic-options